# Oracle: alter sequence snipet not working

Tags: oracle, sequence, ddl

I want to alter my sequence (currently value is 5) up to date with the max value of an ID (currently value is 100).
Here's what I did :

```
alter sequence s_id increment by 100;
select s_id.nextval from dual;
alter sequence s_id increment by 1;
```

And I launch this snipet in SQL developer, when I do `select s_id.nextval from dual`, I expected to have 101, but instead it shows 6.

I'd like to know what the problem is ? **When I execute line by line, I got 101 corrctly.**
Thank you

Comment: Batches of sequence numbers are assigned to each session separately. If you are running separate sessions, a batch on one session may have already been assigned, before the increment was changed (by another session); i.e. won't have effect until the batch is consumed or the session is closed/reopened.

Comment: there's no problem with [your case](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=b4905d3641cf6465451441778f112003)

Comment: @Barbaros Özhan hi it's like this, it does not work https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=5298b68dbdb3035cba4f00fcaa271bd7

Comment: No, it works indeed but need to put the content of the 7th cell( starting with `alter sequence` ) into [seperate cells](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=b4905d3641cf6465451441778f112003)

Answer (score 0):

Is the sequence a indentity-column based sequence? When yes you have to loop until you get the correct value because changing the increment does not work.

With a normal sequence this should work

```
SQL> drop sequence t_seq;

Sequence T_SEQ gelöscht.

SQL> set echo on;
SQL> create sequence t_seq;

Sequence T_SEQ erstellt.

SQL> select t_seq.nextval  from dual;

   NEXTVAL
----------
         1

SQL> select /*csv*/ sequence_name, increment_by,last_number from user_sequences where sequence_name = 'T_SEQ';
"SEQUENCE_NAME","INCREMENT_BY","LAST_NUMBER"
"T_SEQ",1,21

SQL> alter sequence t_seq increment by 100;

Sequence T_SEQ geändert.

SQL> select t_seq.nextval  from dual;

   NEXTVAL
----------
       101

SQL> select /*csv*/  sequence_name, increment_by,last_number from user_sequences where sequence_name = 'T_SEQ';
"SEQUENCE_NAME","INCREMENT_BY","LAST_NUMBER"
"T_SEQ",100,2101

SQL> alter sequence t_seq increment by 1;

Sequence T_SEQ geändert.

SQL> select  t_seq.nextval  from dual;

   NEXTVAL
----------
       102

SQL> select /*csv*/ sequence_name, increment_by,last_number from user_sequences where sequence_name = 'T_SEQ';
"SEQUENCE_NAME","INCREMENT_BY","LAST_NUMBER"
"T_SEQ",1,122
```